# Train distances leaving at certain times

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, problem-solving

> A train leaves Boston to Fort Lauderdale traveling at $125$ mph. An hour later, another train leaves Fort Lauderdale traveling to Boston at a rate of $140$ mph. When the two trains meet each other, which is closer to Boston?

I did $d=rt$ where $d=$ distance, $r=$ rate, and $t=$ time. The rate is $125+140=265.$ The time is $1$ hour. So the distance is $265*1=265.$ Based on the distance and the speed, I would say that the first train is closer.

**I also noticed in this riddle problem no distance was given. Could this be a question that you can not answer without the distance?**

Can someone help me with this problem? Is there a certain way to find the solution and to think about this? I am not to sure.

Comment: What is the distance between Boston and Fort Lauderdale?

Comment: @SherlockHolmes I noticed that this riddle question that I found did not give the distance. I was wondering can this question still be answered.

Comment: @SherlockHolmes I suppose not since there is no exact distance from the question. I think we can make estimates on the distances but it would not be correct.

Comment: Of course they are the same distance from Boston.  Or Paris.

Comment: Nice pickup @AndréNicolas! Didn't see that until I reread the question :P.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I see now. It was right there. I get how they are the same distance. I did the working showing the distance but did not conclude that they are the same distance from boston or paris. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When they meet, they are at the same distance from Boston.  Or Paris. No distance needed. No speeds needed. No times needed.

Comment: Thank you. I noticed that after I looked at the distance part of the question when they meet each other. They will be the same distance in Boston or Paris. It is the same.